# XML File posting through CURL not Hitting the url

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

While I am posting XML content from one server to other server, it is not getting added.
I'm using cURL to post the xml files to another server. But I am getting the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2011 08:13:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.6
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6846cb7e65f6f6d6d87f163a681f0543; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 5721
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This is my code

```
$file_path= WWW_ROOT.$xmlfilename;          
$xmldata = file_get_contents($file_path);
$request = 'http://www.sample.com/someaction';
$postargs = 'xml='.urlencode($xmldata).'&filename='.urlencode($xmlfilename);

// Get the curl session object
$session = curl_init($request);

// Set the POST options.
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Do the POST and then close the session
$response = curl_exec($session);
print_r( $response);
```

Note: allow_url_fopen and curl are enabled in both servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning it like this:

$postargs = array('xml' => urlencode($xmldata), 'filename' => urlencode($xmlfilename))

Both items should then appear in $_POST['xml'] and $_POST['filename'] in the receiving side (or equivalent if not PHP).

**EDIT**

OK you may need to look at streaming the XML file using CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.

See this for a bit of an example http://zingaburga.com/2011/02/streaming-post-data-through-php-curl-using-curlopt_readfunction/

Comment: yes i done like this also.. same issue..... If I am posting large content it may be the problem ? also i posted with small content.. but still same

Comment: OK, if it's very big you might need to stream it... see edit.